# image string altered by v-html in vue 3

Tags: javascript, string, image, vuejs3

Hey everyone I'm trying to pass an image element in to my body content using v-html, but when I pass in my string of html it turns a '?' in my image string into undefined. I'll provide some example code to show what I'm doing

```
<div
    class="article-body"
    v-html="fedArticleContentDesktop"
></div>
```

this is the string I pass into v-html using the fedArticleContentDesktop variable

```
"<img alt="" src="https://example.com/image/example_image_650x735.jpg?resize=690px:*&output-quality=75"  />"
```

this isn't the actual url I'm using but the format is the same, but when the page is rendered it doesn't render the image and when I go to check the elements in the dev tools of the browser the '?' between '.jpg' and 'resize=690px' reads undefined so the src url becomes "https://example.com/image/example_image_650x735.jpgundefinedresize=690px:*&output-quality=75"

I essentially put console logs every where in my code to see if this is being altered at all

I've confirmed in the browser console that the value has the '?' in the create and mount hook this url isn't altered and also I've checked the link to make sure it isn't dead which it is not. Can anyone shed any clarity on why this is happening. I'm currently using vue3 for my development framework

Comment: Quite possibly the error is where you are setting the variable , please include that as well. Also likely is your incorrect usage of quotes, you can not use the same style of quotes inside the string as what you have defined the string. Eg you may need `var string = "A 'quote' inside as string";`

Comment: please show relevant code in the question

Comment: what is your question?